# How to solve the integral equation?

Tags: integral-equations

How to solve the integral equation
$$  \int_{-20}^{x} \left|  \left|  \left|  \left|  \left|  \left|
 \left|  \left| t \right| -1 \right| -1 \right| -1 \right| -1 \right|
-1 \right| -1 \right| -1 \right| \,{\rm d}t={\frac {4027}{2}}?$$

Comment: graph this function to, find the answer

Comment: @ darya khosrotash: Could you kindly elaborate your comment?

Comment: @MarkiyanHirnyk What have you tried ? What does the function's graph immediately show you ?

Comment: @Hippalectryon: I think about that. The  graph says nothing for me.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
$$\int_{-20}^{x}||||||||t|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|\,dt =\\\int_{-20}^{-7}||||||||t|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|\,dt+\\\int_{-7}^{-5}||||||||t|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|\,dt+\\\int_{-5}^{-3}||||||||t|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|\,dt+\\\int_{-3}^{-1}||||||||t|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|\,dt+\\\int_{--1}^{-1}||||||||t|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|\,dt+\\\int_{+1}^{+3}||||||||t|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|\,dt+\\\int_{+3}^{+5}||||||||t|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|\,dt+\\\int_{+5}^{+7}||||||||t|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|\,dt+\\\int_{+7}^{x}||||||||t|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|\,dt=\frac{4027}{2}
$$so 
$$ \int_{-20}^{-7}||||||||t|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|\,dt=(-20-(-7)\cdot(13)\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{169}{2}\\\int_{-7}^{-5}||||||||t|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|−1|\,dt=2\cdot1\cdot\frac{1}{2}
$$so by  simplify 
$$\frac{169}{2} +7\cdot2\cdot1\cdot\frac{1}{2} + \frac{(x-7)(x-7)}{2}=\frac{4027}{2}\\ \frac{(x-7)(x-7)}{2}=\frac{4027-169-14}{2}
$$

Comment: If I don't make an error, the roots are $7+2\sqrt {962},7-2\sqrt{962}$ whereas Maple brings $69.$

Comment: @ darya khosrotash: Are you serious?

Comment: yes ,I am . if 4027 was 4023 $$(x-7)^2=3844 \\x-7=62$$

Comment: Yes, you made an error; the second term of your simplified expression should have been $7\cdot2\cdot1\cdot\frac{1}{2}$ (not $5$). Count the humps in your camel-like diagram, there are 7 of them.  The answer is $x=69$.

Comment: How to obtain $69$ analytically, the question is.

Answer (score 0):

The main tough part is getting a grasp on the function in the integral.  Let
$$
A_0(t) = |t|
$$
and for $n > 0$
$$
A_n(t) = |A_{n-1}(t) - 1|
$$
Then the function integrated is $A_7(t)$ (count the -1's).

Now it is easy to prove (by a two-step induction proof on odd and even $n$) that for all $n \in \Bbb{Z}$
$$
|t| \leq n  \Longrightarrow  A_{n}(t) = |t| - n 
$$
and 
$$
\int_{-n}^{n} A_{n}(t)dt = n $$

So, for $x > 7$, 
$$
\int_{-20}^{-7}A_7(t)dt = \int_{-20}^{-7} (-t-7) dt + 7 + \int_{7}^{x}(t-7)dt = \frac{169}{2} + 7 + \frac{(x-7)^2}{2}
$$
Then 
$$\frac{183}{2} + \frac{(x-7)^2}{2}= \frac{4027}{2}$$
$$(x-7)^2 = 3844 $$
$$x = 62+7 = 69 $$
(The other solution, $x = -55$, clearly does not satisfy the original problem, since the integrand is always non-negative, so an integral from $=20$ to $-55 < -20$ is necessarily negative.)

Comment: @ Mark Fischler: your $A_n(0)=-n$ while $A_n(t) \ge 0.$